# Flutter/Android change background color of Gesture Navigation icon

Tags: flutter, flutter-android

I have an icon set using a transparent image, on the home screen the background is white but when in the Gesture Navigation view the icon above the app screen is blue.  How do I change this background color? (Using flutter)

[image: Gesture Navigation view android]

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet that will reproduce the issue you facing(Gesture Navigation icon)

Comment: All I've done is take the default flutter app and added a transparent icon.  I have no idea where the blue background is coming from, I assume it's the default from either Flutter or Android but I'm not sure.  There is no code to share.

Comment: Could be issue with theme primary color, You can find more about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

I am also having this issue. As a work around, I keep the Material App ThemeData's primary color as white. Then used the Theme widget to override my page theme to use my custom theme.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html

```html
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final _navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  NavigatorState? get _navigator => _navigatorKey.currentState;

  MyApp({super.key});

  // App Routing
  Route<dynamic> _generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    Widget newPage = Container();
    switch (settings.name) {
      case AppRoutes.welcome:
        newPage = const WelcomePage();
        break;
      case AppRoutes.login:
        newPage = LoginPage();
        break;
    }
    return FadeRoute(
      page: Theme(
        data: lightTheme,
        child: newPage,
      ),
    );
  }

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
          BlocProvider<AppBloc>(
              create: (_) => AppBloc()..add(InitializeAppEvent())),
          BlocProvider<AuthBloc>(create: (_) => AuthBloc())
        ],
        child: BlocListener<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
            listener: (_, state) {
              if (state is Authenticated) {
                // Go to Main Page
                _navigator?.pushReplacementNamed(AppRoutes.home);
              } else {
                // Go to Login Page
                _navigator?.pushReplacementNamed(AppRoutes.login);
              }
            },
            child: MaterialApp(
              navigatorKey: _navigatorKey,
              title: 'Flutter Demo',
              theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.white),
              initialRoute: AppRoutes.welcome,
              onGenerateRoute: _generateRoute,
            )));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats the primary color you can change it like this

```
MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    theme: ThemeData(
      primaryColor: Colors.lightGreen,//here.change this one
    ),
  )
```

Comment: Would it be possible to keep the primaryColor as blue because that works well with my theme, but change the background of the icon in this situation? ie: Don't use primaryColor for this icon bg?

Comment: In android res folder check the icons. Theres one adaptive icon too in which the background would be some colour. Try changing that

Answer (score 0):

It isn't from Android. Flutter's MaterialApp already provides a set of attributes for us, including a Prymary Color, ColorScheme, etc.
The reason is obvious, if every developer had to write every theme aspect in every widget coding would be awful. So Material widgets look for a theme, which Material will provide as default, if we don't overide it.

**Know this, the solution is:**

1. Overide some componentes of the whole Theme in the MaterialApp wich is my recomendation. The code bellow is an example of this.
2. Wrap a specifc widget/s with an Theme widget that overides the define Theme for explict specified atributes.
3. Pass a custom theme directly in the widgets you are using. Very common to see in Text widgets when people do  `Text( "some text", style: TextStyle())` (note the *TextStyle*), but this logic is apllied to a bunch of other widgets too, including buttons. Disavantage of this is that you have to manual change every widget, so no auto darkmode and painfull design changes for reasonable size apps. I do not recomend as a go to solution for every widget.

Example of what I meant by overiding the default Theme of your App:

```
MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Association App for AMDKP Integrated Plataform',
        theme: ThemeData(
          colorScheme: ColorScheme(
            brightness: Brightness.light,
            primary: consts.golden1,
            onPrimary: consts.black41,
            secondary: Colors.green.shade500,
            onSecondary: Colors.green.shade300,
            background: consts.greyWhite,
            onBackground: consts.black41,
            surface: Colors.white,
            onSurface: Colors.black45,
            error: Colors.red.shade900,
            onError: Colors.red.shade900,
          ),
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          primaryColor: consts.golden1,
          elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            shadowColor: consts.black41,
            primary: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSurface.withAlpha(150),
            onPrimary: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface,
          )),
          textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
            primary: Colors.white.withAlpha(230),
            backgroundColor: Colors.black87.withAlpha(170),
            textStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
          )),
          inputDecorationTheme: const InputDecorationTheme(
            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: consts.golden1, width: 2)),
          ),
        ),
        home: const HomePage(),
```

So definitely take a look at flutter themes, it will empower your flutter developer skills and you will benefit a lot by using it anyway! :)
Cheers

Comment: Would it be possible to keep the primaryColor as blue because that works well with my theme, but change the background of the icon in this situation? ie: Don't use primaryColor for this icon bg?

Comment: Yes! What Icon widget are you using? IconButton, Icon inside a InkWell/GestureDectecture, other?
If possible, provide the code so I can show you how :)

Comment: no.. its the icon in android when switching between apps.  As in not inside my app...

Comment: You mean the apps icon? I think I complety missed the point then, am sorry.
There should be a solution, but I don't know it.